# NumberFormatter Minimum Not Working Correctly?

Tags: cocoa, nsnumber

I configure a basic NumberFormatter:

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
```

Then I set the minimum variable:

```
numberFormatter.minimum = 1
```

Which, [according to the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter/1417228-minimum) sets:

> The lowest number allowed as input by the receiver.

But when I run the following conversion:

```
numberFormatter.string(from: -1)
```

I get the erroneous output:

> minus one

Why isn't the minimum value being acknowledged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the documentation says with the misleading term *input* is, that it does not allow to convert a string with a value lower than the minimum value into a number. This is, because it is hard to test, whether a *string* has a lower value, esp. in a localized form

You go the other way from a number to a string. For this scenario it is easy to test yourself, whether the boundaries are met. Therefore the number formatters does not check the boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, the minimum value only prevents the user from inputting a lower number when the number formatter is attatched to, e.g., a text field. It'll still allow you to format lower numbers yourself.

What you probably need to do is make sure your value isn't less than the minimum value yourself.

Comment: So, how is the user prevented from entering a lower value? Number formatters does not have a long wire to the user's keyboard. ;-)

Comment: By attaching it to a text field in Interface Builder or by assigning it to the text field's `.formatter` property.

Comment: By *attaching to a text field* there is till no long wire to the keyboard. The text field sends its value to the formatter, not the other way round. This is, what he does. The difference is, that the text field is sending the string value, while he is sending the numeric value.

Comment: Yes. Do the same: Send the string value `@"-1"` to the formatter and try to get the numeric value using `-numberFromString:`. You get `nil`. At least I get.

Comment: Right, but when it's attached to an `NSTextField` directly the text field presents a dialog saying the number is too low.

Comment: Exactly what I said: The *text field* is displaying a dialog, not the formatter. The formatter does not have a connection to the user. It is a helper of the text field and does not act its own.

Comment: The final answer is correct, but the explanation is wrong. (As your comments are.) The problem is not the role of the number formatter but the direction of conversion. This has nothing to do with text fields or custom code. There is no need even to mention text fields.

Comment: Except that that's exactly how the minimum value is used. Your answer says the same thing in different words.

Comment: Anyway, it doesn't matter. He can change the accepted answer if he wants to.

Comment: This is not the point. *I*  upvoted your answer, too, because the final result is okay. But my answer says something different with different words.